# USB not showing in Boot Menu or Bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kali-linux, bios, boot-menu

I am trying to boot Linux from my usb drive but it doesn't seem to show USB as an option in the bios or boot menu.

pics of bios and boot menu
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU1Iv.jpg

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How old is your computer?

Comment: Quite new, I bought it a year or 2 ago. Lenovo Y50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to deactivate the option "Secure Boot". Changing the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy might work too, at least from the top of my head I remember doing something similar.

Comment: Changing the UEFI to legacy worked! Thank you!